# charAt method, exam paper Q

Tags: java

> Which of these statements concerning the charAt() method of the String
> class are true?
>
> Select 2 options
>
> A. The charAt( ) method can take a char value as an argument.
>
> B. The charAt( ) method returns a Character object.
>
> C. expression char ch = "12345".charAt(3) will assign 3 to ch.
>
> D. The expression char ch = str.charAt(str.length()) where str is "12345", will assign 3 to ch.
>
> E. The index of the first character is 0.
>
> F. It throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException if passed an value higher than or equal to the length of the string (or less than 0).
>
> G. It throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if passed an value higher than or equal to the length of the string (or less than 0).

The answer from the questions is A,E . My answer is E, F

The paper reasons the following : Both - `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and
`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, extend `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and
although in practice, the `charAt` method throws
`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, it is not a valid option because the
implementation is free to throw some other exception as long as it is an
`IndexOutOfBoundsException`

But this doesnt really make sense, Im pretty sure that `charAt()` throws an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Is the papers answer incorrect ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29 Says is throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: The official implementation throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` but it would be perfectly valid that another impementation throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since a String is backed by a char array, or simply an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So neither F or G is correct because it's implementation dependant.

Comment: Instead of typing all this and asking what type of Exception is thrown, wasn't it easier to just try it instead and see which one is thrown?

Comment: Even if it does, actually, throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, you shouldn't rely on it because the documented contract of the method is to throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Oracle could decide, in Java 9, to throw a BrandNewException which extends IndexOutOfBoundsException, without breaking the documented contract. If you rely on StringIndexOutOfBoundsException being thrown, you rely on an implementation detail that might change in the future.

Comment: I've never understood how remembering random specifics about some API makes for good exam questions. Go figure.

Comment: @Zavior: agreed. But maybe the test allows javadoc to be consulted, and measures the ability of students to read and understand it. That would be a very, very good idea given the number of questions asked here that have their answer literally written in the javadoc.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I really try and understand why something works a certain way, not just how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second answer is incorrect: `charAt` throws [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

Choice 'A' is true as well, because Java compiler will convert `char` to `int` for you implicitly (although the situation when it makes sense to use `char` as an index would look artificial).

You are right about the choice 'E' being correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this: A - true, E - true

A - true as each char is also implicitly an int, i.e. you can do `int x = 'a'`;
E - obviously true, this is a basic true statement;

B - false as it returns char not Character;
C - false as indexing is 0- based;
D - false as it will throw exception;
F, G - just check the JavaDoc or try an example; these are trivial.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice ;) And I was hesitating about F and G.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys much appreciated

Best answer in my opinion :

Even if it does, actually, throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, you shouldn't rely on it because the documented contract of the method is to throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Oracle could decide, in Java 9, to throw a BrandNewException which extends IndexOutOfBoundsException, without breaking the documented contract. If you rely on StringIndexOutOfBoundsException being thrown, you rely on an implementation detail that might change in the future.

Java OCA SE7 exam on wed !